# Can I write Join Queries with SQL Application block without using SP

Tags: sql, join

I want to write a select query with multiple joins and get a data set. In the project we use SQL Application block for the db access.

I tried sql readers, data adapters but it seems like without using a SP I can't write a sql query with multiple joins.

I can't use a SP because it's a one time data access in order to do a data fix.

Eg: The following code doesn't work.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
    {
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
    }
```

Here the sqlQuery has a lengthy select query with multiple joins.
eg:

```
sqlQuery = "select a.Date, a.ID from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.ID = b.ID "
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work" with code you've provided? Are you getting some exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It's a silly mistake. It is an issue with my sql query. When I copy the query from SQL to C#, I have missed the spacing of each end of line.
Following is the corrected code after I added the spaces.

```
string sqlQuery = "select e.RelatedID from tblA e "
                                + "join (select MAX(r.CreatedDate) as RecendDate, r.RelatedID "
                            + "from tblA r "
                            + "where r.RelatedTable = 'tblB' and r.Publishers in (2,3) "
                            + "group by r.RelatedID) x on e.RelatedID = x.RelatedID and e.CreatedDate = x.RecendDate "
                            + "where e.RelatedTable = 'tblB' and e.Publishers in (2,3) and e.RemoveFlag = 1 "
                            + "union "
                            + "select distinct(l.ListingID) from  tblA e "
                            + "inner join tblB l on e.RelatedID = l.ListingID "
                            + "inner join tblC os on l.StateID = os.StateID "
                            + "where os.StateCode = 'COMPLETE' ";
```

Comment: a verbatim string literal would help here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx This would avoid the need to concatenate separate strings together